# Swift: Changing password for user on Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have three UITextFields, in which I am getting the old password, new password, and confirm password. I am getting the alert success, but my password for the user is not changing. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if password != confirmPassword {
        createAlert(title: "Error", message: "Passwords do not match")
    } else {
        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
        let credential: AuthCredential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: (user?.email)!, password: oldPassword!)
        user?.reauthenticateAndRetrieveData(with: credential, completion: {(authResult, error) in
            if error != nil {
                self.createAlert(title: "Error", message: "failed")
            }else{
                Auth.auth().currentUser?.updatePassword(to: self.password!) { (error) in
                    print("Error")
                }
                self.createAlert(title: "Success", message: "Password change successful!")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you log them out as well? Need to refresh the token...